# Postgree double group by repeating attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.3

I have table with some columns: id, user_id, message_id, message_type; for example:

```
  id: 1, user_id: 1, message_id: 4, message_type: 'Warning'
  id: 2, user_id: 1, message_id: 5, message_type: 'Warning'
  id: 3, user_id: 1, message_id: 6, message_type: 'Warning'
  id: 4, user_id: 2, message_id: 4, message_type: 'Error'
  id: 5, user_id: 2, message_id: 1, message_type: 'Exception'
  id: 6, user_id: 1, message_id: 2, message_type: 'Exception'
  id: 7, user_id: 1, message_id: 3, message_type: 'Exception'
  id: 8, user_id: 2, message_id: 4, message_type: 'Exception'
```

I want to get grouping result like news in social networks. On columns user_id and message_type, while message_type repeating. And need LIMIT 20 ORDER BY id DESC.
Example:

```
  id: 8, user_id: 2, message_id: 4, message_type: 'Exception'
  id: {6,7} user_id: 1, message_id: {2,3}, message_type: 'Exception'
  id: 5, user_id: 2, message_id: 1, message_type: 'Exception'
  id: 4, user_id: 2, message_id: 4, message_type: 'Error'
  id: {1, 2, 3}, user_id: 1, message_id: {4, 5, 6}, message_type: 'Warning'
```

How to do it with best performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found only 1 way:

1. With window function `lead()` find a moment when was changed dict `(user, message type)`
2. With window function `sum()` set sequnce number for each new dict
3. Group by sequence and select what you need:

Checking:

```
create table test (
  id serial primary key,
  user_id integer,
  message_id integer,
  message_type varchar
);

insert into test (user_id, message_id, message_type) 
values 
(1, 4, 'Warning'),
(1, 5, 'Warning'),
(1, 6, 'Warning'),
(2, 4, 'Error'),
(2, 1, 'Exception'),
(1, 2, 'Exception'),
(1, 3, 'Exception'),
(2, 4, 'Exception')
;

select 
    array_agg(grouped.id) as record_ids,
    grouped.user_id,
    array_agg(grouped.message_id) as message_ids,
    grouped.message_type
from (
    select changed.*, 
        sum(changed.changed) over (order by changed.id desc) as group_n
    from (
        select tt.*,
            case when lag((user_id, message_type)) over (order by tt.id desc) is distinct from (user_id, message_type) then 1 else 0 end as changed
        from test tt
    ) changed
    order by id desc
) grouped
group by grouped.group_n, grouped.user_id, grouped.message_type
order by grouped.group_n
;
```

Result:

```
record_ids | user_id | message_ids | message_type 
------------+---------+-------------+--------------
 {8}        |       2 | {4}         | Exception
 {7,6}      |       1 | {3,2}       | Exception
 {5}        |       2 | {1}         | Exception
 {4}        |       2 | {4}         | Error
 {3,2,1}    |       1 | {6,5,4}     | Warning
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `array_agg` function should do the trick:

```
SELECT   user_id, 
         message_type, 
         ARRAY_AGG (DISTINCT id), 
         ARRAY_AGG (DISTINCT message_id)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY user_id, message_type
```

Comment: In this example, grouping all messages and all users. Thank you for correcting the question, maybe I incorrectly formulated it.
I want to make a group of consecutive identical messages for users.

Comment: Do not grouping rows with ids 5 and 8, because before it messages another user.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/399c3/2